# SagePay Protocol 3.00 Encryption Error with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography, opayo

Spent the day struggling with getting AES/CBC/PCKS#5 encryption for SagePay Forms Protocol 3.00

Helpfully the SagePay .Net integration kit's functions for encryption are in a compiled DLL which makes the kit next to useless for understanding how the encryption needs to work.

After many many attempts to get the encryption right I keep running into this error with SagePay:

"5068: The encryption method is not supported by this protocol version"

Anyone who has some working encryption / decryption functions that work with SagePay for Protocol 3.00 using AES/CBC/PCKS#5 I'd really appreciate them, as I'm sure many others would too...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a fair bit of reading and looking through loads of examples that don't work I have a solution in vb.net - I hope this works for someone else too:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Namespace Cypher

    Public NotInheritable Class SagePayAESCBCPKCS5

        ' Singleton pattern used here with ensured thread safety
        Protected Shared ReadOnly _instance As New SagePayAESCBCPKCS5()
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As SagePayAESCBCPKCS5
            Get
                Return _instance
            End Get
        End Property


        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Function DecryptText(encryptedString As String, encryptionKey As String) As String
            Using myRijndael As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
                myRijndael.BlockSize = 128
                myRijndael.KeySize = 128

                myRijndael.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey)
                myRijndael.IV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey)

                myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
                myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None

                Dim encByte As [Byte]() = HexStringToByte(encryptedString)

                'Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV)
                Dim plaintext As String = ""
                ' Create the streams used for decryption. 
                Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(encByte)
                    Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                        Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)

                            ' Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                            ' and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                            srDecrypt.Close()
                            csDecrypt.Close()
                            msDecrypt.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using

                End Using
                Return plaintext

            End Using
        End Function


        Public Function EncryptText(plainText As String, encryptionKey As String) As String
            Using myRijndael As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
                myRijndael.BlockSize = 128
                myRijndael.KeySize = 128

                myRijndael.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey)
                myRijndael.IV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey)

                myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
                myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

                Dim encrypted As Byte()
                ' Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV)

                ' Create the streams used for encryption. 
                Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
                    Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                        Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt)
                            'Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
                        End Using
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
                    End Using
                End Using
                'Dim encrypted As Byte() = EncryptStringToBytes(plainText, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV)
                'Dim encString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)
                Dim encString As String = ByteArrayToHexString(encrypted)
                Return encString
            End Using
        End Function

        Protected Shared Function HexStringToByte(hexString As String) As Byte()
            Try
                Dim bytesCount As Integer = (hexString.Length) \ 2
                Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(bytesCount - 1) {}
                For x As Integer = 0 To bytesCount - 1
                    bytes(x) = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)
                Next
                Return bytes
            Catch
                Throw
            End Try
        End Function

        Public Shared Function ByteArrayToHexString(ba As Byte()) As String
            Dim hex As New StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2)
            For Each b As Byte In ba
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
            Next
            Return hex.ToString()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

To Encrypt For SagePay

```
Dim EncryptedString as string = "@" & Cypher.SagePayAESCBCPKCS5.Instance.EncryptText(strPost, strEncryptionPassword).ToUpper()
```

To Decrypt

```
Dim DecyptedString as string = Cypher.SagePayAESCBCPKCS5.Instance.DecryptText(strCrypt.Remove(0, 1), strEncryptionPassword)
```

Hope that helps someone out there, this almost drove me mad today!

Comment: This could be tidied up a fair bit especially the EncryptText function... but it is working!